# How to hide sensitive data in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I am creating chatroom using python based on mongoDB. I want to hide a url in this script

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

url="" #the url i don't want to reveal
cluster = MongoClient(url)
db = cluster["priya"]
chat = db["chat"]
countm = db["countm"]
passdb = db["pass"]
```

and where can i hide this url

Comment: You can create environmental variable (.env) and import the url from it.

Comment: You want to hide it from ...?

Comment: if i give it to my friend and how can he able to run it?

Comment: @KlausD. i want to give this script to others and i don't want them to find that url

Comment: Similar questions have been asked here hundreds of times. The short answer is that hiding information is not the solution, and developing one is far less trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use some kind of KeyVault. You store API keys, logins, passwords to KeyVault, where access has only authorized users.

The second option is to create as mentioned `.env` file, this file put into `.gitignore` you never want to git logins and passwords. Python has [library](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) `python-dotenv`.

Usage:

**.env**

```
YOUR_SECRETS={"login": "login", "pass": "strong_pass"}
```

**main.py**

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
print(os.environ["YOUR_SECRETS"])
```